# Unable to pass quoted string to rm directly with xagrs

Tags: bash, pipe, xargs

To find some file with `grep` and delete them with `rm` I tried following command -

```
$ ls | grep 2019 | xargs -i rm \"{}\"
```

That did not work. Got the following error message -

```
rm: cannot remove '"2019-05-10 00:00:00-TO-2019-05-10 23:59:59_PDT_disconnection_info.csv"': No such file or directory
```

Looks like `xargs` is taking quotes literally. So, tried `echo`ing instead of passing directly -

```
ls | grep 2019 | xargs -i echo \"{}\" | xargs rm
```

This worked.

Why does not it work without `echo`ing?

Comment: Why not just `rm *2019*`???

Comment: Oh, did not know `rm`  accepts wildcards.

Comment: It doesn't, shell expands wildcards

Comment: Does that mean I can pass wildcard arguments to any command?

Comment: Yes, to any command that accepts a list of filenames. The command never sees the wildcard, it just gets the list of matching filenames.

Answer (score 1):

The proper quoting is done by `xargs`, there is no need to quote it again. Just:

```
 ... | xargs -i rm {}
```

Or better, because rm accepts multiple arguments, just do:

```
 ... | xargs rm
```

> Why does not it work without echoing?

When not used with -i, -I, -d or similar, the `xargs` utility handles proper quoting in input with double or single quotes or escaping with a backslash. The quotes are removed by the second `xargs` and `rm` is passed unquoted string. From [man xargs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html):

> ```
>  .... xargs reads
>  items from the standard input, delimited by blanks (which can be
>  protected with double or single quotes or a backslash)
> ```

Compare:

```
$ echo "\e\r\t\q\e" | xargs -t echo
echo ertqe 
ertqe
```

Also see [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).